# Steam crash right after launch (16.04)

Tags: steam, 16.04

I just installed ubuntu 16.04 lts and would like to try steam, so I installed steam via `sudo apt install`, the installation is all good. After the first update, steam crashes when it try to start the login dialogue and it crashes everytime I try to launch it. Following is the console output when I start steam the first time.

```
leo@leo-ultra:~$ steam
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[2016-04-26 17:20:08] Startup - updater built Jun 16 2014 11:16:02
[2016-04-26 17:20:08] Verifying installation...
[2016-04-26 17:20:08] Unable to read and verify install manifest /home/leo/.steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12.installed
[2016-04-26 17:20:08] Verification complete
[2016-04-26 17:20:08] Downloading Update...
[2016-04-26 17:20:08] Checking for available update...
[2016-04-26 17:20:09] Package file tenfoot_misc_all.zip.b9c015520018655499338cfc2c3a3159e28bbe14 missing or incorrect size
[2016-04-26 17:20:09] Package file tenfoot_dicts_all.zip.c74a3a9beb77a280cfd8761b901a80ed0f6a3173 missing or incorrect size
[2016-04-26 17:20:09] Package file tenfoot_fonts_all.zip.vz.b99d15e7a78b99cea4d0abb6c3f3badc0c6ad441_12073430 missing or incorrect size
[2016-04-26 17:20:09] Package file tenfoot_ambientsounds_all.zip.20ccff954777943069dd2c57576216f5f1db7389 missing or incorrect size
[2016-04-26 17:20:09] Package file tenfoot_sounds_all.zip.vz.7a3cc0ba5f5309183bca660227b8e0afa9922629_1223056 missing or incorrect size
[2016-04-26 17:20:09] Package file tenfoot_images_all.zip.vz.a63c03af96b4e61e506c7603dedf52caeeeb23ac_23617298 missing or incorrect size
[2016-04-26 17:20:09] Package file tenfoot_all.zip.vz.5f26b8510f1f89130c1619965e9a676d07282d04_1930448 missing or incorrect size
[2016-04-26 17:20:09] Package file resources_misc_all.zip.vz.5b8f09b1f407d80780688930b071e340fe22600d_2028216 missing or incorrect size
[2016-04-26 17:20:09] Package file resources_all.zip.vz.c5c4d7641e2f0135a89abb660964a1346fd58c37_5010677 missing or incorrect size
[2016-04-26 17:20:09] Package file strings_en_all.zip.ad680029c2a337b9961697503d1576397fd30e91 missing or incorrect size
[2016-04-26 17:20:09] Package file strings_all.zip.vz.bd2a329d462766923cc73d6d22f92d9402014fa8_1952126 missing or incorrect size
[2016-04-26 17:20:09] Package file remoteui_all.zip.vz.c3eceeaa19b297032eb8511f44f7f9a49bfdfe01_141152 missing or incorrect size
[2016-04-26 17:20:09] Package file public_all.zip.vz.a22c7b0fafad2456bd0c86c27eb025e501764d6a_791601 missing or incorrect size
[2016-04-26 17:20:09] Package file bins_ubuntu12.zip.vz.af540293f5cd021f3140bcc79b7473b4bf87957b_15035944 missing or incorrect size
[2016-04-26 17:20:09] Package file bins_pub_ubuntu12.zip.vz.b6d7b5f80b1776d0e9e4d2036affeabfe248b751_9030238 missing or incorrect size
[2016-04-26 17:20:09] Package file bins_sdk_ubuntu12.zip.vz.6972ced92a5d8ea963c962eddbdd7af36bad6126_9507455 missing or incorrect size
[2016-04-26 17:20:09] Package file bins_codecs_ubuntu12.zip.vz.11b6edae15c9060d91c0730ecbdad978a1bc7f0a_1830793 missing or incorrect size
[2016-04-26 17:20:09] Package file bins_misc_ubuntu12.zip.9e5c4f09c8cbdfb1b04cc8d0c93da2fee3b09bb1 missing or incorrect size
[2016-04-26 17:20:09] Package file webkit_ubuntu12.zip.vz.388ca9c5c49a79520a1e7017c80f40451280d67f_30507894 missing or incorrect size
[2016-04-26 17:20:09] Package file miles_ubuntu12.zip.vz.1b7a19905752a14821fcba42b49fe1a1ed6ba836_299743 missing or incorrect size
[2016-04-26 17:20:09] Package file sdl2_ubuntu12.zip.vz.f37f83cc217f9155ab964addb080ddb1549db2c8_288005 missing or incorrect size
[2016-04-26 17:20:09] Package file steam_ubuntu12.zip.vz.7b47b25161daebd31ef637281c736e12a7a7d484_1414353 missing or incorrect size
[2016-04-26 17:20:09] Package file runtime_part0_ubuntu12.zip.4742a6f20429e36d3068bc3e1be64bcaa5b039ca missing or incorrect size
[2016-04-26 17:20:09] Package file runtime_part1_ubuntu12.zip.33e62d95c5ee2b8ec63d0ed7aca0f6f5928d00e9 missing or incorrect size
[2016-04-26 17:20:09] Downloading update (0 of 245,361 KB)...
... I deleted some lines here as they are just Downloading update (x of 245, 361 KB)...
[2016-04-26 17:21:24] Downloading update (245,361 of 245,361 KB)...
[2016-04-26 17:21:24] Download Complete.
[2016-04-26 17:21:24] uninstalled manifest found in /home/leo/.steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12 (1).
[2016-04-26 17:21:25] Extracting package...
[2016-04-26 17:22:00] Installing update...
[2016-04-26 17:22:03] Cleaning up...
[2016-04-26 17:22:03] Update complete, launching...
[2016-04-26 17:22:03] Shutdown
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
[2016-04-26 17:22:19] Startup - updater built Mar 31 2016 19:10:48
[2016-04-26 17:22:19] Verifying installation...
[2016-04-26 17:22:19] Unable to read and verify install manifest /home/leo/.steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12.installed
[2016-04-26 17:22:19] Verification complete
[2016-04-26 17:22:19] Downloading update...
[2016-04-26 17:22:19] Checking for available updates...
[2016-04-26 17:22:20] Download complete.
[2016-04-26 17:22:20] uninstalled manifest found in /home/leo/.steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12 (1).
[2016-04-26 17:22:20] Extracting package...
[2016-04-26 17:22:35] Installing update...
[2016-04-26 17:22:39] Cleaning up...
[2016-04-26 17:22:39] Update complete, launching Steam...
[2016-04-26 17:22:39] Shutdown
Restarting Steam by request...
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/leo/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
[2016-04-26 17:22:39] Startup - updater built Mar 31 2016 19:10:48
[2016-04-26 17:22:39] Verifying installation...
[2016-04-26 17:22:39] Verification complete
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
```

second time I launch steam:

```
leo@leo-ultra:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
[2016-04-26 17:49:09] Startup - updater built Mar 31 2016 19:10:48
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2016-04-26 17:49:09] Checking for update on startup
[2016-04-26 17:49:09] Checking for available updates...
[2016-04-26 17:49:10] Download skipped by HTTP 304 Not Modified
[2016-04-26 17:49:10] Nothing to do
[2016-04-26 17:49:10] Verifying installation...
[2016-04-26 17:49:10] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2016-04-26 17:49:10] Verification complete
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
leo@leo-ultra:~$
```

Comment: Try sudo apt-get purge steam and then delete the .steam folder (Ctrl + H to see it)  in your home folder. Afterwards, install steam again.